# Perl system() not working with sed

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I have a line `` system( `sed -i 's/[ 0-9]+) //' fileName` ); `` in a  perl script that runs through to completion. But the file is not edited.
When I run `sed -i 's/[ 0-9]+) //' fileName` on the shell it runs fine and edits the file as intended. Why would they have different results, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure why the command in the back ticks isn't modifying the file for you, but are you sure you want to use the output of the `sed` command as the parameter to `system`?

Comment: I would also suggest that 'shelling out' to `sed` is unnecessary, given `perl` can do regex-like text processing quite well.

Comment: @tjd I was using ` where i wanted " and that was part of the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
system( `sed -i 's/[ 0-9]+) //' fileName` );
```

First backticks execute a system command and return the output from it. So you are calling system() on the output from sed, which is probably not what you want. You might do this:

```
system(sed => -i => 's/[ 0-9]\+) //', 'fileName' );
```

And shelling out to sed is rather unnecessary anyway, as perl can do anything that sed can, e.g.:

```
$^I = 1;

@ARGV = 'fileName';
while (<>) {
  s/[ \d]+\) //;
  print;
}
```

Comment: I'd also be asking whether it was even necessary to call `sed` from within `perl` as the latter has pretty comparable text processing capability.

Comment: That would be `s/[ \d]+\) //` to match the sed behaviour

Comment: I tried `system(sed => -i => 's/[ 0-9]+) //', 'filename' );` and the output is the same as before, an unedited file. EDIT: adding \ before the + fixed it and it works

Comment: @Borodin i need to remove digits 0-9 AS WELL as any spaces

Comment: @hehe3301: Yes, and your original sed removes an opening parenthesis and a space after the digits

Comment: @Borodin the file has strings "100) foo" as well as " 20) bar" and I need to remove everything before the foo and the bar